# Google Sheet get the most recent entry based on criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am not an excel spreadsheet expert or google sheet expert and I have a spreadsheet where I keep track of my workout progress on a google sheet. I keep track of the weight and the reps per set on a weekly basis. Every week, I have to keep going back and finding the most recent entry. This becomes time consuming when there's more entries, and different type of exercises that are recorded. Is there a formula to retrieve the most recent entry based on a set of criteria?

[image]

So on the above data, I would get... 135 & 8 for the weight & rep for the 1st set, 135 & 8 for the weight & rep for the 2nd set, so on and so forth...

[image]

Any help would be great! thank you

I tried QUERY, MAXIFS,SORTN, SORT but to no avail does not return the correct result.

[image]

```
=sortn(sort('Workout Journal'!A:E,5,false),99^99,2,2,false)

=QUERY('Workout Journal'!A:N,"select C where A="Barbell Squat' and E=date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(max('Workout Journal'!E2:E)),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure it out and quite very simpler than what I thought!

So in the template sheet, for

To get the Last Entry for Weight

```
=MAXIFS('Workout Journal'!C:C,'Workout Journal'!A:A,A277,'Workout Journal'!B:B,B277,'Workout Journal'!E:E,MAXIFS('Workout Journal'!E:E,'Workout Journal'!A:A, A277))
```

To get the Last Entry for Reps

```
=MAXIFS('Workout Journal'!D:D,'Workout Journal'!A:A,A277,'Workout Journal'!B:B,A277,'Workout Journal'!E:E,MAXIFS('Workout Journal'!E:E,'Workout Journal'!A:A, A277))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try `REDUCE()` with `FILTER()`.

```
=QUERY(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(B2:B7),LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:E,B2:B=x),5,FALSE),1)))),"offset 1",0)
```

[image]

Comment: You can remove QUERY and put TOCOL(,1) as the initial value of REDUCE. TOCOL(,1) is a 0x1 pseudo-array that doesn't "stack". `=REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),UNIQUE(B2:B7),LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:E,B2:B=x),5,FALSE),1))))`

Comment: @z.. Interesting... I wasn't aware of behavior of `TOCOL(,1)`. New learning to me. Thank you dear.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work when you start getting a different set of exercises. For example, I could have a another set of exercises within the same data set. 

Chest Press  1 135 8 9/16
Chest Press  2 135 8 9/16
Chest Press  3 135 8 9/16
Shoulder Press  1 50 8 9/16
Shoulder Press  2 50 8 9/16
Shoulder Press  3 50 8 9/16
Chest Press  1 135 8 9/17
Chest Press  2 135 8 9/17
Chest Press  3 135 8 9/17

Comment: @jojopogi Are they true date or just string?

Comment: @Harun24hr - yes, they are true date strings.